# Is there a difference between starting an application from the OS or from adb

Tags: android, android-intent

I do have a curious error in my application. 
My app crashes (don't mind the crash, I roughly know why - classloader) when I start the application from the OS directly, then kill it from the background via any Task Killer (this is one of the few ways to reproduce the crash consistently -> simulating the OS freeing memory and closing the application) and try to restart it again.

The thing is, if I start the application via adb shell using the following command:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.my.packagename/myLaunchActivity
```

I cannot reproduce the crash.

So is there any difference in how Android OS calls the application as opposed to the above call?

EDIT: added the manifest (just changed names)

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<manifest android:versionCode="5" android:versionName="1.05" package="com.my.sample" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
<application android:icon="@drawable/square_my_logo" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.my.InfoActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape"></activity>

    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.my2.KickStart" android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>

    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.my2.Launcher" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/></manifest>
```

starting the com.my2.Launcher from the adb shell

Comment: How are you restarting it "from the OS"?  Are you using the launcher icon, or the recent tasks?  The latter will not necessarily invoke the launcher activity in the new process, but can go directly to whatever was on top of the task stack, so could get you into a perfectly valid, but yet unhandled state.

Comment: have been using the icon primarily sofar, just tried using recent tasks, both causing the same crash. Currently investigating the task stack, but was generally curious since as I said, I was not able to reproduce the crash when starting the intent manually via adb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I can see is that if you launch the app from the launcher icon, the Intent includes the CATEGORY "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" and using the `adb shell am` it does not.

Also, when you launch via the launcher icon, the Intent flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED` (0x200000) is set, in the `adb shell` case it is not.

Not sure if any of that would make a difference in your crash behaviour, but it answers the question.

Comment: Thank you very much, this has helped a lot, it did not directly correlate with my crash but led me to find the culprit -> using SDK 2.1 https://github.com/cleverua/android_startup_activity#readme
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2373
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5277

Comment: Heh heh. Yep. That's my favorite Android bug. Look also at http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26658 that one is mine ;-)

Comment: However, this problem is STILL there in 4.0, so it hasn't been fixed yet. It isn't just a problem in 2.1